# Play store rejected - deprecated Personalized Ad Consent SDK

Tags: android, actionscript-3, google-play, admob, air

I got 30 days notice from google play store. That i have to remove Personalized ad sdk. And replace it with ump.

1. The app update got rejected - "We have detected that your app includes the deprecated Personalized Ad Consent SDK".
2. I have removed Personalized Ad Consent SDK -> The app got rejected again with the same reason.(Personalized Ad Consent SDK)
3. I have sent an EMPTY app, no sdks, no code. just "hello world" to -> close testing - The app got rejected again with the same reason.(Personalized Ad Consent SDK).

I have sent an empty app with NO SDK No CODE and got REJECTED on the same reason -

<"We have detected that your app includes the deprecated Personalized Ad Consent SDK, which is not approved for use in child-directed services. The SDK has been deprecated in favor of the User Messaging Platform SDK and must be updated">

If any one has encountered this violation or multiple rejection even that he fixed the issue. I whould love to hear how he handle it.

Comment: Hmm, check if any of the libraries that get included into your template project are using "something" like a personalized ad consent SDK or its pieces, no matter how small. If you  couldn't find any, start disabling libraries one by one until the test publish would succeed. As a possible workaround, install whatever software you use to develop your app(s) from scratch to a virtual machine, then assemble an empty hello-world app and try publishing that. But I don't know what to do should the last measure result in publishing failure with the same error.

Comment: Thank you.                                                                              I have sent an empty App. No sdk, no libary, no code.just hello world.

Comment: Are you using an old AIR sdk? what version you are using?